# Laptop appears to run on AC even with battery on

Tags: laptop, power-supply, battery

I am using a Lenovo laptop, Ideapad series. A few months back, the laptop battery started to be malfunctional (shuts down without warning) and so I tried to remove its battery. I have failed to do so as one screw cannot be unscrewed, it appears to have been deformed.

I had no choice then but to find a different solution, that is, to disable the battery without removing it. I found a guide online that says to do this, I must disable the battery in *Device Manager* in Windows 10, and it worked, or so I thought.

Recently, I switched my OS to Linux, and the laptop still appears to run on AC, then I realized, the thing I did with device manager in Windows 10 must not work since I've changed my OS.

Upon researching about how I can replicate disabling the battery in Linux, I learned that **you cannot actually disable it**. I'm confused, then why would my laptop appear to run on AC? When I unplug it, laptop shuts down, and would only turn on when plugged in.

I'm planning to have its battery replaced, but not as of the moment.

Comment: Note that the battery can also be disabled on Linux.

Comment: @harrymc how so?

Comment: Added an answer for Ubuntu/Gnome.

Comment: Find somebody with "handy" skills to drill out your damaged screw without damaging your laptop.  This isn't difficult to do and there are many methods but require "finesse" when working inside of a laptop.  If you can find a small enough bit (yourself).. believe it or not, you can actually operate a drill bit "by hand" (or pliers) to remove a tiny screw if you are patient enough and by hand means very little risk to your hardware.  You only need to drill off the little cap on the screw, not the whole screw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your battery has failed completely (or malfunctioned in some other way). You cannot disable the battery in Lenovo laptops, indeed, most laptops.

So now it will not start on the battery. You have seen this.

Accordingly you must (a) plug in the AC Adapter to start the computer; and (b) get the battery replaced as soon as practical for you.

Using the laptop on AC only means the risk of instant shutdown with current data loss and possibly (enough shutdown) some damage to the operating system.

**Follow up for new battery:**  Lenovo laptops (and others) support Battery Threshold charging.  Use Lenovo Vantage to set the battery for maximum 80% charge when plugged into AC for a long time (semi permanent).  80% charge is the generally accepted value for constant AC connection. This helps prevent damage to the battery.

Comment: So then the battery has depleted / died because if is not charging.

Comment: Certainly not because of my attempt, since I did not even got close to removing the battery. Got stuck in the screwing part. Continuing with the issue; given that I would risk data loss, that thing with the OS, and probably harming the hardware with the occasional unwarranted shutdowns, is it safe running my laptop like this for the time being?

Answer (score 0):

The following answer is taken from the Ask Ubuntu post
[How can I disable the battery?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1143204/how-can-i-disable-the-battery)

---

**Gnome settings**

Actualy it should be possible to disable it by setting:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power active false
```

but for some reason it doesn't work anymore.

**GNOME Shell extensions**

However, there are GNOME Shell extensions that you may try to workaround it.

- [Icon Hider](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/351/icon-hider/) - may help you remove parts of gnome panel, but the battery icon is probably a part of aggregateMenu, so removing it will also remove whole power/settings menu
- [Extend Panel Menu](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1201/extend-panel-menu/) - but with this exention you can split aggregateMenu into separate icons and then use extension's setting to disable one of them

Edit: **beware**, I found one of these extensions conflicting with my Ubuntu setup. I had to remove them because my Gnome desktop wasn't loading (I had only black screen with just cursor on it). In case it happens [switch to anoher TTY](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/167386/how-to-switch-between-tty-and-xorg-session), log in and type:

```
cd .local/share
mv gnome-shell gnome-shell.bak
```

then reboot

**Pretending you are not on laptop**

There's a APT package called [laptop-detect](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/laptop-detect.1.html).

> This package provides a simple shell script which attempts to determine whether it is being run on a laptop (or similar portable machine). It is mainly useful for installers.

While runing this script in debug mode:

```
laptop-detect -D
```

it brings the idea of tricking GNOME that you're not on a laptop.

It might be useful if you want to work on AC-only, with i.e. disassembled battery.

I won't tell you how to do this, but you might want to try to figure it out on your own, based on laptop-detect output.

One thing is for example `/sbin/modprobe battery`. So first step will be to blacklist this module with modprobe config.

Another thing is `/sys/devices/virtual/dmi/id/chassis_type`, but it's more tricky, because it's related to Linux kernel and changing this value may even require changing its source code somwhere in [drivers/firmware/dmi-id.c](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/6f0d349d922ba44e4348a17a78ea51b7135965b1/drivers/firmware/dmi-id.c#L58). It's rather something for hardcore linux users ;)

Other places related to laptop battery (for the sake of google-searches):

- /sys/class/power_supply
- /proc/acpi/battery
- /proc/apm